# Could not find or load main class when Running java program using Ant?

Tags: java, ant

I am learning Ant to run Java programs with and without building Jar Files.

Here is my simple program i want to run

```
public class ForDemo {

int i = 0;
byte b = 0;
short s = 0;
double d = 0;
float f = 0;

public ForDemo() {
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + i);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ForDemo();
}
}
```

And the build.xml file for Ant

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <project default="run" basedir="." name="">
 <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
 <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->

 <target name="compile">
  <javac srcdir="." destdir="." includes="**/*.java" target="1.8">

    <classpath refid="classpath.base" />
  </javac>

  </target>
   <target name="run"  depends="compile">
    <java fork="true" failonerror="yes" classname="ForDemo">
     <arg line=" "/>
     <classpath refid="classpath.base" />
    </java>
   </target>  <!-- Libraries on which your code depends -->

   <path id="classpath.base">                                                                                                                           
      <fileset dir="libs">                                                                                                                          
        <include name="**/*.jar" />                                                                                                          
     </fileset>                                                                                                                                   
     </path>  
    </project>
```

But i am getting this error

```
  run:
  [java] Error: Could not find or load main class ForDemo

  BUILD FAILED
```

When i run ant in the parent directory of java file command on my Linux Mint 17.1 x64 with oracle jdk 1.8b40.

Comment: Take a look at this guide: https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

Comment: @DSF but how can i run a java program directly without building jar file??

Comment: Try replacing your run target with the one from the guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included the output dir (`"."`) of your javac task on the classpath of your java task, so the `ForDemo` class that you compile there is not on the classpath when java executes.

You could include that dir in your java task like this:

```
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${classpath.base}"/>
        <pathelement location="."/>
    </classpath>
```

Comment: code Do i have to create a new class path like, `<path id="classpath.base"><fileset dir="libs"><include name="**/*.jar" /></fileset><fileset dir="."><include name="**/*.*" />                                                                                                          
     </fileset>                                                                                                                                   
  </path>  ` like this and is it safe ??